# SPSS Partial Correlation not giving a number?

Tags: correlation, spss

I am trying to use a partial correlation on my data that should include the high temp, low temp, and total count....and control three other factors.  When I run a simple correlation, Analyze-Correlate-Bivariate, I am able to attain correlation values.  When I run Analyze-Correlate-Partial, then select the high temp, low temp, and total count as my variables and the rest as my controlling for I do not get any correlation values and it gives me a df of 0.  There are five rows for each variable, could it be there is just not enough data to do a partial?  Please any help as to why the simple correlation works but the partial correlation does not work would be great.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check would be the pattern of missing values in the variables